# Find the right CRS for projecting this CSV WKT geometry

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to work out the right CRS for projecting this  WKT geometry. I have it saved as a CSV.
It displays but it's in totally the wrong place. Should be in Ghana, not the ocean.

POLYGON ((11.3811111111 -7.59,  11.3811111111 -7.4422222222,  11.325555555555 -7.4422222222,  11.325555555555 -7.59))

Comment: looks like lon/lat - what have your tried so far?

Comment: It's less an issue of *projecting* than of *defining* it correctly.  As a lon,lat pair, it *is* in the ocean; as lat,lon, it's in Mali.

Comment: hi thanks, you are right, the lon lat need to be fliped. 
I used this and It worked.
CRS -  WGS84 
then I used - toolbox - Swap X and y